# Sorting a list by integer that contains strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following strings in a list:

```
De Aza, Alejandro; CWS; 153; 607; 84; 160; 27; 4; 17
Hunter, Torii; DET; 144; 606; 90; 184; 37; 5; 17
Hamilton, Josh; LAA; 151; 576; 73; 144; 32; 5; 21
Choo, Shin-Soo; CIN; 154; 569; 107; 162; 34; 2; 21
```

Split where there are semi-colons. I need a way to sort the list by the 5th value, it should be:

```
Hunter, Torii; DET; 144; 606; 90; 184; 37; 5; 17
De Aza, Alejandro; CWS; 153; 607; 84; 160; 27; 4; 17
Choo, Shin-Soo; CIN; 154; 569; 107; 162; 34; 2; 21
Hamilton, Josh; LAA; 151; 576; 73; 144; 32; 5; 21
```

The problem is that if I use `key=itemgetter(5)` then it assumes the values are strings.

Comment: You can use `key=lambda x: int(x[5])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by the integer value of the fifth item, use

```
 key=lambda x: int(x[5])
```